VirtualBox: Увеличить время блокирования экрана
Использую Windows 10. Установлена версия VirtualBox 7.0. Создал виртуальную машину с Xubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.
У меня на компе 2 монитора. Обычно на правом виртуалку запускаю, а на левом мониторе работаю локально на ПК. Так вот, обратил внимание, что если нет активности на виртуалке в течении 5 минут (замерил специально), то дисплей виртуалки блокируется, и чтобы его включить необходимо вводить пароль:

Пробовал открыть в самой Xubuntu -> Настройки -> Менеджер питания: и увеличил время в настройках дисплея. В данный момент все 4 вкладки выглядят так:




но это никак не помогло, всё равно дисплей виртуалки блокируется через 5 минут. Может быть, в настройках самой программы VirtualBox надо искать? Я полазил, но ничего там не нашёл:

Можете пожалуйста подсказать, как мне это настроить? Как увеличить время блокировки экрана виртуальной машины?

Это вроде не в настройках питания, а в настройках хранителя экрана (соседняя кнопка).

@HolyBlackCat Спасибо! Ты прав, помог пункт настроек Хранителя экрана!
Настройки -> Хранитель экрана:


Вкладка "Хранитель экрана" -> Считать компьютер неактивным после: установил например 15 минут. Также установил Тему: Летающий Xfce.


Вкладка "Блокировка экрана" -> Блокировать экран хранителем экрана: снял галку.


В итоге экран виртуальной машины блокируется после 15 минут простоя. Не просто чёрный экран, а летающие крыски. При наведении курсора экран активируется без ввода пароля.

@Dev18 , готово, оформили :-))

Ответ от пользователя @HolyBlackCat
Настройки -> Хранитель экрана:

Вкладка "Хранитель экрана" -> Считать компьютер неактивным после: установил например 15 минут. Также установил Тему: Летающий Xfce.

Вкладка "Блокировка экрана" -> Блокировать экран хранителем экрана: снял галку. В итоге экран виртуальной машины блокируется после 15 минут простоя. Не просто чёрный экран, а летающие крыски. При наведении курсора экран активируется без ввода пароля.


